# 2009 cards | combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-game-theory

Consider 2009 cards which are lying in sequence on a table. Initially, all cards have their top face white and bottom face black. The cards are enumerated from 1 to 2009. Two players, Amir and Ercole, make alternating moves, with Amir starting. Each move consists of a player choosing a card with the number k such that $k < 1969$ whose top face is white, and then this player turns all cards at positions $k,k+1,\ldots,k+40$. The last player who can make a legal move wins.

(a) Does the game necessarily end?

(b) Does there exist a winning strategy for the starting player?

Comment: This is an impartial game like Nim, where the moves available are the same for both players.  The Sprague-Grundy theorem, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem is your friend.

Comment: @Ross: I don't see how that brings us any closer to solving (b). The theorem tells us that every position is equivalent to a nimber, but actually finding those nimbers is at least as difficult as finding the game values of the positions, no?

Comment: @joriki:  in the theorem it describes how to find the value of a position as the minimum excluded value.  But yes, it can be a lot of work in a big tree.  I hoped that thought down that line would (and the IMO suggester probably thought it should) bring the answer.

Comment: @Ross: It's probably helpful to think along those lines, but for the concrete work of finding the game value (which is what (b) asks) it seems like a complication -- you have to traverse the same tree as you would for the game value, just that instead of working out a $0$ or a $1$ based on $0$s and $1$s you work out nimbers based on nimbers, though in the end unless you want to combine the game with some other game all you're interested in is whether these are $0$ or not...

Comment: What is the purpose of card number 2009?

Comment: @Christian: it is traditional to include the year in at least one of the IMO questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution on page 780 of Dusan Djukic, Vladimir Jankovic, Ivan Matic, Nikola Petrovic, The IMO Compendium; A Collection of Problems Suggested for The International Mathematical Olympiads, 1959-2009, which I found on Google Books.

Answer (score 4):

It would be worth telling us what you have tried.

**Some hints:**

- Are there are a finite number of possible positions (and if so what
  is an upper bound)?
- Can there be a cycle of positions (consider the card with the
  smallest number turned over)?
- Will the starting player have a winning strategy if initially there
  are only 41 cards? 42? etc?

Comment: Actually, I think the first non-trivial number of cards is 82.  (Or maybe 83, depending on what you consider trivial.)

Comment: @Ilmari: I think you mean $82$. Each turn turns over $41$ cards.

Comment: @joriki: Thanks, corrected.